# Angular JS: interceptor doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, interceptor

In my SPA I catch every 401 response from REST requests. From there I don't redirect to login page immediatly, but first I check to the backend if the problem is that the token has expired or not. If not (the user is not known) I redirect to login, but if it was an expired problem, I generate a new token then I run again the request that previously failed into a 401. Here is the code for my interceptor:

```
    var $http, loginService;


    return function (promise) {
        return promise.then(function (response) {
            return response;
        }, function (response) {


            if (response.status === 401) {
                $http = $http || $injector.get('$http');
                loginService = loginService || $injector.get('loginService');

                var defer = $q.defer();
                var promiseToken = defer.promise;

                var configPreviousRequest = response.config;
                console.log(configPreviousRequest);
                var url = configurationService.serverUrl + "mobile" + configurationService.apiVersion + "/verify";
                var request = $http.post(url, {'code': loginService.getVmmToken()});

                // Get the token. If success, we try to login again
                return request.then(
                    function (responseVerify) {
                        loginService.setVmmsToken(responseVerify.data);
                        loginService.setAuthentificationToken();
                        configPreviousRequest.headers.vmmsToken = responseVerify.data;

                        return $http(configPreviousRequest);
                    },
                    function () {
                        $location.path('/login');
                    });


            }
            return $q.reject(response);
        });
    };
```

But here is the result in Chrome Network tool. All methods are not in the correct number (called too many times for /verify and /blocks)

[image]

So I logged (with console.log(configPreviousRequest);) to see what happens. Here are logs:[image]

We clearly observe that for one 401 error, I intercept it many times.
And I have no clue why :)

Has someone any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Check the version of AngularJS you are using. Latest version is 1.2.14